# WFR Not working

Tags: workflow

I have a workflow that should fire when a case comment is created if both fields one text and one picklist contain specific values. 
I have to do this a formula and not criteria as they are looking to case.

AND(
Parent.Previous_Status__c, 'Customer Outstanding', this is a text field
TEXT(Parent.RelatedProduct__c, "Payroll")) this is a picklist

Comment: That workflow formula shouldn't compile. Are you getting an error when trying to save the workflow rule, or is it just not behaving the way you want it to?

Comment: My best guess is that you need to use the equals operator `=` to do your comparison on the text field, and `ISPICKVAL()` for the comparison on the picklist. It'll help if you [edit] your question so that your workflow rule makes sense and is syntactically correct.

Comment: Thank you for responding, I have tried multiple version this one is the latest and has the following error                                                                                                                       IF(
Parent.Previous_Status__c, 'Customer Outstanding',
ISPICKVAL(Parent.RelatedProduct__c, "Payroll"))                                                                           Error: Incorrect parameter type for function 'IF()'. Expected Boolean, received Text

Answer (score 0):

Your formula should look like the following:

```
AND(
    Parent.Previous_Status__c = "Customer Outstanding", 
    ISPICKVAL(Parent.RelatedProduct__c, "Payroll")
)
```

Use `=` to compare text values, and `ISPICKVAL` to compare picklist values.

Comment: Thank you soooo much .

Comment: @Lorr You're welcome!